# unable to understand the logic behind this

Tags: java

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Boolean b=false;
        if(b=true)
        {
            System.out.println("TRUE");
        }
        if(b=false){
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Although it might seem to be a very simple problem for the most of you, but i am unable to understand that when i run this code the output is TRUE.

Since `=` is an assignment operator so therefore in both the cases it should come out to be true, since the values are assigned i.e. `if(b=true) = true` (valid) and `if(b=false) = true` (valid). And since there is no else condition in this therefore it should give both TRUE and FALSE as the outputs.

Comment: `b=false` returns `false`.

Comment: The output is correct. `if(b=false)` assigns `false` to `b`, so `b` is `false` and that's why the `if` block is not entered.

Comment: @Baadshah Question is that the output is showing only "TRUE", but i think it should be both "true" and "false"

Comment: Why? You assign false to b and check whether false is true. This is false, so why should it print "FALSE" ?

Comment: what is the need of **if** u can remove it, it isn't doing anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically correct in what you think. However assignments do not return true if they succeed and false if they don’t succeed (actually, assignments cannot not succeed; invalid assignments would either be a syntax error or throw an exception).

Instead, assignments return the value that has been assigned.

So `b = true` returns `true`, and `b = false` returns `false`. That’s why the condition of your second if won’t be true.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of such assignment is always a right-hand side of it. 
So result of (b=false) is false.

It is defined in the java language specification here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

`if(b=false)` is evaluated as False. Here you are assigning the value of false to the variable `b`.  So it becomes `if(false)` which means that `if` block is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(b=true)
```

means that `true` value is set to `b` and now in the bracket `b`'s value will be replaced, so JVM treats it like

`if(true)`  //variable b replaced with it's value.

That is why you are getting such output which is expected from JVM. `=` is an assignment operator.
We must use `==` operator to compare boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(b=false)
```

is different than

```
if(b == false)
```

if(b==false) checks if b is false than enters the if section, BUT
if(b=false) aqssigns false to ba and then does not enter to the if section because it is false.

Answer (score 0):

the inner part of if statement executes only when its true 
that is if (true) inner statement executes 
if(false) inner statement doesnt execute
in the second if statement ur assigning false to b so it doesnt execute ...

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement must evaluate to a boolean type. Because of that, the value contained in b is automatically unboxed when the conditional statement is evaluated, and works the same way as the primitive type boolean works. So since if(b=true) is true, it returns the value. It evaluates as if(true) assigning the value of true to the variable b and if(b=false), assigning the value of false to the variable b and exiting since it is false.